# Can I write off any of my car purchase if I get an allowance?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, tax-deduction

I was offered an option to get a car allowance when I was hired on a year and a half ago. Last year, I bough a new truck to use for this purpose. I get an allowance plus a mileage rate that is about half of the federal amount.

Truck $30k
allowance $500/mo
mileage rate ~.25/mile
average monthly miles 3200

I do some personal use, but I've put probably 19000 of the 20k miles on it for work (I drive another car sometimes too). I bought it March of 2017.

I file itemized. I think there's a 2% threshold for writing off expenses. Is there anything I can do to save on my taxes for this vehicle?

Comment: I think that writing it off **and** getting an allowance is *double dipping*.

Comment: Is your allowance included in Box 1 of your W-2?

Comment: The allowance is not included in box 1.

Comment: If the mileage write off is double dipping I can see that not working, but the fact that I had to purchase the vehicle to qualify for the policy--does that mean the purchase can be written off?

Comment: The allowance would probably be double dipping too. If you're not including the allowance as income, then you probably can't claim the truck payment (or at least, the first $500 of it) as outgo.

Comment: @RonJohn Not automatically. I think he just has to show that his expenses for business use of the truck exceed his reimbursement, and then he is allowed to deduct the excess amount. See IRS Form 2106, you list your expenses, then subtract the reimbursement, then deduct the excess.

Comment: @RonJohn Excluding the allowance from income and claiming it as a deduction is double dipping (a deduction is basically money you're claiming should be part of your income, so you can't deduct money unless it's part of what would otherwise be your income).